# get all points of all counters in emgu cv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to draw a rotated rectangle. The canny image is not one counter it is a set of counters. So I want to get all points of all counters. e.g.

```
Points[] pts = points of all counters.
```

Please see attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The canny show all edges in your image, not an external contour. This one way (but not the only one) to do object detection (foreground / background extraction). 
The following snippet extract object roi (Min area rect) by using a canny edge detector. Be carrefull about canny thresh parameteres comming from otsu threshold.

Hope it helps.
[Detection result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5StVJ.jpg)

```
Image<Gray,byte> imageFullSize = new Image<Gray, byte>(imagePath);
Rectangle roi = new Rectangle(Your Top Left X,Your Top Left Y,Your ROI Width,Your ROI Height);
//Now get a roi (No copy, it is a new header pointing original image
Image<Gray,byte> image = imageFullSize.GetSubRect(roi);
//Step 1 : contour detection using canny
//Gaussian noise removal, eliminate background false détections
image._SmoothGaussian(15);
//Canny thresh based on otsu threshold value: 
Mat binary = new Mat();
double otsuThresh = CvInvoke.Threshold(image, binary, 0, 255, ThresholdType.Binary | ThresholdType.Otsu);
double highThresh = otsuThresh;
double lowThresh = otsuThresh * 0.5;
var cannyImage = image.Canny(lowThresh, highThresh);   
//Step 2 : contour extraction
Mat hierarchy=new Mat();
VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
CvInvoke.FindContours(cannyImage,contours,hierarchy,RetrType.External,ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
//Step 3 : contour fusion
List<Point> points=new List<Point>();
for(int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
{
    points.AddRange(contours[i].ToArray());
}

//Step 4 : Rotated rect
RotatedRect minAreaRect = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(points.Select(pt=>new PointF(pt.X,pt.Y)).ToArray());
Point[] vertices = minAreaRect.GetVertices().Select(pt => new Point((int)pt.X, (int)pt.Y)).ToArray();
//Step 5 : draw result
Image <Bgr,byte > colorImageFullSize =new Image<Bgr, byte>(imagePath);
Image <Bgr,byte > colorImage =colorImageFullSize.GetSubRect(roi);
colorImage.Draw(vertices,new Bgr(Color.Red),2 );
```

Comment: Thank u Sir, It helped me to go ahead. But i am facing problems when I changed the IC.

Comment: Also please tell me how to use ROI with this code. Thanks

Comment: Thank u sir it helped me a lot.